# Upper bound on Contractive Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, upper-lower-bounds

I am considering a contractive sequence of the form

$$x_{n+1} = (1-ax_n)x_n$$

where $x_0\in[0,1/a)$. This sequence is obviously decreasing

$$x_{n+1} < x_n$$

but I would like an upper bound on the convergence rate. And I have no idea how to approach this problem nor what keywords to google about it, so any clue/direction would be helpful.

I have also reason to believe (from the context this sequence stems from) that the convergence speed is probably something like $O(1/n)$ but do not have any proof for that other than that I get similar rates if I tackle the problem from a different angle.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/207585/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3034255/42969 for a proof of $x_n \sim 1/(a n)$.

Comment: @MartinR thanks :)

Comment: It is possible to provide non-asymptotic bounds, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4256565/445105